# FFmpeg Error ( no such file or directory error)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, converters

I am trying to convert multiple videos in a directory with ffmpeg. Command runs properly but the error comes up is no such file or directory exist. while the file exist in the same directory.

The command I am using is: for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %a in ('dir /B *.avi') do ffmpeg -i "%a.avi" "%a.mp4"

My file name is like (my video file.avi) which are causing error. file with name without spaces like (file1.avi, file2.avi ) are working fine.

Comment: Perhaps you should quote `%a` at `for ...` part too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default value IFS to '\n' to solve it.

`(IFS=$'\n'; do ffmpeg -i "%a.avi";)`